# ERROR: undefined reference to... what is wrong?

Tags: c++, class, header, g++

I getting a undefined reference error when I try compile the code. I only just be be to test the Grafo class fuctions

grafo.h:

```cpp
#ifndef GRAFO_H
#define GRAFO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>


/*  Classe Grafo - Matriz de adjecencia  */
class Grafo
{
    public:
        //  Atributos
        int num_vertices;
        int *vertices; 
        int **arestas;
        char tipo;

        //  assinaturas dos metodos
        Grafo(int nv,char t);
        void printGrafo();

};
#endif
```

grafo.cpp

```cpp
#include "grafo.h"

Grafo::Grafo(int nv,char t);  
Grafo::void printGrafo();

Grafo::Grafo(int nv,char t){
    num_vertices = nv;
    vertices = new int[num_vertices];
    tipo = t;

    //criar matriz
    arestas = new int *[num_vertices];
    for(int i = 0; i < num_vertices;i++){ arestas[i] = new int[num_vertices];}

    // inicializar valores da matriz
    for(int i = 0; i < num_vertices;i++){
        vertices[i] = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < num_vertices;j++){
            arestas[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

}

void Grafo::printGrafo(){
    std::cout << " | ";
    for(int i = 0; i < num_vertices;i++){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
        for(int i = -3; i < num_vertices;i++){
        std::cout << "_";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_vertices;i++){
        std::cout << i << " | ";
        for(int j = 0; j < num_vertices;j++){
            std::cout << arestas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "grafo.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

int main(){
  Grafo G = Grafo(5,'D');
  G.printGrafo();
}
```

when I try compile with command g++ main.cpp -o main.exe. I recive the following error msg:

> /tmp/ccPxPLjS.o: In function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined
>   reference to`Grafo::Grafo(int, char)' main.cpp:(.text+0x35):
>   undefined reference to `Grafo::printGrafo()' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Someone may help-me with this job? >.<

Comment: You haven't *defined* `Grafo(int, char)` and `Grafo::printGrafo()`

Comment: you've defined the parameterized constructor

Comment: Concerning the constructor, `Grafo::Grafo(int, char)`: implementation is missing (in `grafo.h` or `grafo.cpp`). Concerning `Grafo::printGrafo()`, you may have forgotten to note `grafo.o` in the list of objects to link your application.

Comment: Sorry i forget to include the Grafo::Grafo on Grafo.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove first lines from `Grafo.cpp` file:

```
Grafo::Grafo(int nv,char t);  
Grafo::void printGrafo();
```

These are causing errors in compilation (GCC):

```
grafo.cpp:3:27: error: declaration of 'Grafo::Grafo(int, char)' outside of class is not definition [-fpermissive]
 Grafo::Grafo(int nv,char t);
                           ^
grafo.cpp:4:8: error: expected unqualified-id before 'void'
 Grafo::void printGrafo();
        ^~~~
```

Then include all source files into compilation invocation:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp grafo.cpp
```

This will cause sources to compile properly, if done like this:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

it will cause similar errors as described in your question:

```
ccVmPgnr.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `Grafo::Grafo(int, char)'
ccVmPgnr.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `Grafo::printGrafo()'
```

Comment: worked proprely. Thank you for your help! :)